# Convert rtf code to Math Formula

Tags: c#, rtf

I have rtf code which i want to convert into Math Formula in Asp.Net MVC

**rtf code :-**

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset161 Calibri
>   Greek;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}} {*\generator Msftedit
>   5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs18  M\sub r\nosupersub  = M x (2 - \lang1033\f1\'e2\f0 )\f2\par

which will display math formula as follow[image]

i am referring this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-convert-rtf-to-plain-text) but it is for desktop app, so how can i achieve this in Asp.Net MVC

Comment: You write a parser yourself. What do you even mean by `Math Formula` ? A specific language? MathML? An R script? Do you want to *render* this as HTML ?

Comment: If you want to *render* this as HTML, you'll find a lot of duplicate questions. Your code doesn't have to *understand* the RTF snippet or the expression, just convert it to HTML

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no i want to render rtf code as math formula, and i don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: Render *where*? As HTML? An image? Then google for `rtf render html` or `convert rtf to html`. You'll find the duplicates immediatelly.

Comment: There are a couple on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter)  and [MSDN Code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e) articles that show how to write an RTF to HTML converter. The code for the MSDN article [is here](https://github.com/mmanela/MarkupConverter)